# C++ inline base class method must be explicitly resolved?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, clang, inline

I'm having a weird issue with inheritance and method resolution in my class hierarchy. The code is being compiled with clang++ 5.0 with `-O0`. I have two classes like so:

```
class PrintBase
{
protected:
    static wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> sConverter;

public:
    virtual void PrintChar(wchar_t ch) = 0;
    inline  void PrintChar(char ch)
    {
        PrintChar(sConverter.from_bytes(ch)[0]);
    }

    virtual void PrintString(const wstring& str) = 0;
    inline  void PrintString(const string& str)
    {
        PrintString(sConverter.from_bytes(str));
    }
};

class Print: public PrintBase
{
public:
    virtual void PrintChar(wchar_t ch) override;
    virtual void PrintString(const wstring& str) override;
};

void Print::PrintChar(wchar_t ch)
{
    // do stuff
}

void Print::PrintString(const wstring& str)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

If I construct a Print instance `Print* pnt = new Print();` and call `pnt->PrintChar('c');` it correctly calls the inline base class method, does the conversion, and then correctly calls the implemented virtual override in the derived class.

If I call `pnt->PrintString("test");` or `pnt->PrintString(string("test"));` or `pnt->PrintString(someString);` I get the error:

```
No viable conversion from 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char>>' to 'const basic_string<wchar_t, char_traits<wchar_t>, allocator<wchar_t>>'
```

...with some variation on the constness of the of the "from" type. Calling `pnt->PrintString(L"test");` or the like will work as one would expect. And I can force it to call the inline string& function with `pnt->PrintBase::PrintString("test");`

Why would it be able to correctly resolve and call the inline char method in the base class, but be unable to do so for the string& method without explicitly resolving the scope?

Comment: I accidentally submitted the question early and editing just went down for site maintenance! If you stumble upon this before I get a chance to finish the question, please check back shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setup you have is a classic example of an overriding function *hiding* other inherited overloads.

When a function is overridden in a derived class, that overriding function hides all the other overloads from the base class. Overload resolution comes after selecting the name, so once `PrintString` is determined to refer to `Print::PrintString`, it will never consider `PrintBase::PrintString`, even if the former does not accept the arguments being supplied and the latter would.

The most straightforward way is to bring in the inherited, but not overridden names into the derived class with a `using` declaration:

```
class Print: public PrintBase
{
public:
    virtual void PrintChar(wchar_t ch) override;
    using PrintBase::PrintChar;

    virtual void PrintString(const wstring& str) override;
    using PrintBase::PrintString;
};
```

I don't believe calling `PrintChar('x')` through a `Print` object actually calls the inline overload. What it would really do is initialise the `wchar_t` from the `char` you pass in. Is it possible it just does the same thing as the inline version would in your case?

Comment: Yeah, the using directives worked perfectly. I hadn't realized this would be a problem because usually anything with the same name that was getting overridden would all be virtual. About the char/wchar_t conversion, though, I confirmed in the debugger it's calling the inline function. I can step in, watch it call the conversion function, and then forward the result to the virtual function. Very weird.

Comment: @BrighamToskin Note that this applies even if the other overloads are `virtual`, but not all of them are overridden.

Comment: @BrighamToskin About the `char` overload: that *is* weird. Are both the calls happening throught the same (static) object type?

Comment: Yeah, I allocate a Print object, assigned to a Print*. If I add a call `pnt->PrintChar('c');` with a breakpoint and step-in, I hit the inline code.